# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm doing the "Predic Future Sales" on Kaggle, and as I'm a beginner with machine learning and Python I'm getting some help with this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/patriciasakugawa/predict-future-sales-part-1-eda/comments).

In the part II of this link, Patricia use this method to change the date format :

```
# Change the date type
date = train.date.apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))

# Create 3 new features for year, month and day
train['year'] = date.dt.year
train['month'] = date.dt.month
train['day'] = date.dt.day
train.head()

# Remove the "date" feature
train = train.drop('date', axis=1)
```

My problem is that I found difficult to understand this line :

`date = train.date.apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))`

in particularity this : **train.date**

date is a method of train? or date is the name of the column we want to select with the dataframe "train"?

Thanks in advance and I hope I formulated my question as clear as English isn't my first language,
Pierre.

Comment: In your context date should be name of a column.

Comment: Thanks ManojK, any reason why I get "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'" when i run this line on Jupyter?

Comment: you can try type(train.date) and if the output is pandas.Series than you can be sure it's a column.

Comment: 1) can you print `'date' in train.columns` and make sure it is `True`. 2) use `date = pd.to_datetime(train.date)`.

Comment: It happens probably because you've already run the code that dropped the date from the dataframe.
train = train.drop('date', axis=1)
So if you are trying to execute the 
date = train.date.apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
it can't find the date in your object. For it to work you need to redefine your dataframe from the very beginnig once again.

Comment: @PierreJ -  Is there any column named 'date' in your dataset?

Comment: @KarlOlufsen Amazing ! Thanks everyone.